# SIM800L модуль проблема с UART

Tags: arduino, uart

Всем привет, у меня возникла проблема с общением МК и модуля.

Вот сам модуль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подключаю я его через аккумулятор, через пару секунд после включения он регистрируется в  сети и становится доступным для звонка.

А вот пообщаться с ним через UART не получается. 
Пробовал через arduino UNO и через PL2303HX, модуль просто молчит.

Есть предположение что виновником является не согласование уровней.

[Вот даташит SIM800L](http://mt-system.ru/sites/default/files/documents/sim800_series_serial_port_application_note_v1.01.pdf)

---

Прошу помочь с решением данной проблемы. Буду признателен любой информации.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему должно работать через uno.
[Тут](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/LoNet_-_GSM/GPRS_Breakout) рекомендуют воспользоваться at tester для проверки.